# MySQL select from all tables with a column name

Tags: mysql

Let's say I query this:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like 'coduser';
```

it returns a list of tables which contains the column "coduser":

```
users
messages
passwords
photos
```

It's a 20+ items list.

I need to search on those tables all occurrences where "coduser" is equal to "5OEWP1BPSV".

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablenamehere WHERE coduser = "5OEWP1BPSV";
```

but I'm not using anything other than MySQL to do this.

Basically just search all tables where there is a column called "coduser" and coduser = "5OEWP1BPSV".

Comment: You mean "valueofcollumnhere" should be dynamic?

Comment: @P.Salmon no, it's static.

Comment: Then there is no question..your query will work fine.

Comment: well, it's not returning all of the ocurrences of "a static value here" on those tables :/

Comment: Prove it..give me some sample table names and the actual query code you used.

Comment: @P.Salmon i edited it, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic sql and given the small numbers involved a cursor would be appropriate

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key , codeuser varchar(20));
create table t1(id int auto_increment primary key , codeuser varchar(20));

insert into t(codeuser) values
('aaa'),('5OEWP1BPSV');
insert into t(codeuser) values
('bbb');

drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin
declare tablename varchar(20);
declare finished int;
DECLARE GRD_CUR CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT TABLE_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE COLUMN_NAME like 'codeuser';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET FINISHED = 0;
OPEN GRD_CUR;
LOOPROWS:LOOP

FETCH GRD_CUR INTO tablename;

IF FINISHED = 0 THEN
    LEAVE LOOPROWS;
END IF;
#build and execute dynamic sql
set @sql = concat('SELECT  * FROM ' , tablename, ' WHERE codeuser = "5OEWP1BPSV"');
#select @sql;
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
END LOOP;
close grd_cur;  
end $$
delimiter ;

call p();
```

Answer (score -2):

Loop over the returned list of tables, and for each table in that list perform a

```
SELECT *
WHERE columnnamehere = "valueofcolumnhere";
```

Bear in mind that this will give you separate lists for each table within that FOR loop, so you would have to concatenate these in some way to get a complete list.

Comment: oh, how do i loop?

Comment: @Wiliam Brochensque junior-  stop apologising everybody starts out ignorant.

Comment: Depends on which language you are using, but you will need a FOR loop. Search online for a tutorial on FOR loops for the language you are using.

Comment: @ollieyeahlong - this is a specific mysql question and the answer should be mysql.

Comment: i'm just using mysl. Or is it not possible with only mysql?

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior it's possible with mysql, but it's way more complex and hard to debug. Way simpler will be do implement it using python/ruby or maybe even bash